# Ubuntu booting problem

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu 12 alongside Ubuntu, but when I start my PC there is no option to enter Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Please help me out. I have a lot of my university assignments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant in the first sentence. Do you mean you installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside *Windows 7*?

Answer (score 0):

Check your grub configuration file:
/etc/default/grub

Ensure you have the positive number countdown such as the 10 selected below.
Ensure you have Hidden timeout commented out:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Run the following to commit your changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```